# R in RStudio with doParallel - CPU usage of each core reduces after initial ~10 secods

Tags: r, cpu-usage, doparallel

I'm using `RStudio 2023.03.0` on my machine with `Windows 10 Pro 22H2`.
My machine has 8 cores and I'm running my code on a cluster of 7 cores with `doParallel`:

```
  cores=detectCores()
  cl <- makeCluster(min(cores[1]-1,7))
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))

  output <- foreach(
    j=1:100,
    .export=c('myfunc'),
    .packages=c('mypackages')
  ) %dopar% {
    ### do stuff in parallel
  }
```

After initial ~10-30 seconds where each core uses ~12.5% of the available CPU - which brings the overall CPU usage at that moment to ~100% - the CPU usage of each core reduces drastically to only ~8.5% - which brings the total CPU usage to ~65%:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas where this comes from or how to increase the CPU usage again?
Thanks!

**Update / additional Info:**

I tried the same with `%dofuture%` and `clusterApply` and with both packaged I have the same issue.

Sometimes the time where I have maximum CPU usage is larger (Minutes to a few hours) sometimes it directly starts with 8,6% per core.

For reference, my session_info():

```
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  German_Germany.utf8
 ctype    German_Germany.utf8
 tz       Europe/Berlin
 date     2023-08-11
 rstudio  2023.03.0+386 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
 pandoc   2.19.2 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)


─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package               * version    date (UTC) lib source
 abind                   1.4-5      2016-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 askpass                 1.1        2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 backports               1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 base64enc               0.1-3      2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cachem                  1.0.8      2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 callr                   3.7.3      2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 car                     3.1-2      2023-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 carData                 3.0-5      2022-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 checkmate               2.2.0      2023-04-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cli                     3.6.1      2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cluster                 2.1.4      2022-08-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 codetools               0.2-19     2023-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 colorspace              2.1-0      2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 corrplot              * 0.92       2021-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cowplot               * 1.1.1      2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 crayon                  1.5.2      2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 crul                    1.4.0      2023-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 curl                    5.0.0      2023-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 cvar                    0.5        2022-11-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 data.table            * 1.14.8     2023-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 devtools              * 2.4.5      2022-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 dgof                  * 1.4        2022-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 digest                  0.6.31     2022-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 DistributionUtils       0.6-0      2018-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 doFuture              * 1.0.0      2023-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 doParallel            * 1.0.17     2022-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 dplyr                 * 1.1.1      2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ellipsis                0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 evaluate                0.21       2023-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fansi                   1.0.4      2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fastmap                 1.1.1      2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fBasics                 4022.94    2023-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fGarch                * 4022.89    2022-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fitdistrplus            1.1-11     2023-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 flextable               0.9.1      2023-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 fontBitstreamVera       0.1.1      2017-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fontLiberation          0.1.0      2016-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fontquiver              0.2.1      2017-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 foreach               * 1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 foreign                 0.8-84     2022-12-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Formula                 1.2-5      2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 fs                      1.6.2      2023-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 future                * 1.32.0     2023-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 future.apply            1.10.0     2022-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gbutils                 0.5        2022-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gdtools                 0.3.3      2023-03-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 GeneralizedHyperbolic   0.8-4      2018-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 generics                0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gfonts                  0.2.0      2023-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ggplot2               * 3.4.2      2023-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ghyp                    1.6.3      2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 globals                 0.16.2     2022-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 glue                    1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gmp                   * 0.7-1      2023-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gridExtra               2.3        2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 gtable                  0.3.3      2023-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 hash                  * 2.2.6.2    2022-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Hmisc                 * 5.1-0      2023-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 hms                     1.1.3      2023-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 htmlTable               2.4.1      2022-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 htmltools               0.5.5      2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 htmlwidgets             1.6.2      2023-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 httpcode                0.3.0      2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 httpuv                  1.6.11     2023-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 iterators             * 1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 jsonlite                1.8.4      2022-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 KernSmooth              2.23-20    2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 knitr                   1.42       2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ks                      1.14.0     2022-11-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 later                   1.3.1      2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 lattice                 0.20-45    2021-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 lifecycle               1.0.3      2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 listenv                 0.9.0      2022-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 magrittr                2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 MASS                  * 7.3-58.2   2023-01-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Matrix                  1.5-3      2022-11-11 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 matrixStats           * 0.63.0     2022-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 mclust                  6.0.0      2022-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 memoise                 2.0.1      2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 mime                    0.12       2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 miniUI                  0.1.1.1    2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 moments               * 0.14.1     2022-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 munsell                 0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 mvtnorm                 1.1-3      2021-10-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 nnet                    7.3-18     2022-09-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 numDeriv                2016.8-1.1 2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 officer                 0.6.2      2023-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 openssl                 2.0.6      2023-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pacman                  0.5.1      2019-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 parallelly              1.35.0     2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 PerformanceAnalytics  * 2.0.4      2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pillar                  1.9.0      2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pkgbuild                1.4.0      2022-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pkgconfig               2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pkgload                 1.3.2      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 plyr                    1.8.8      2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 pracma                  2.4.2      2022-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 prettyunits             1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 processx                3.8.1      2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 profvis                 0.3.8      2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 promises                1.2.0.1    2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ps                      1.7.5      2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 purrr                   1.0.1      2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 quadprog                1.5-8      2019-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 quantmod                0.4.22     2023-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 R6                      2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 ragg                    1.2.5      2023-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rbibutils               2.2.13     2023-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Rcpp                    1.0.10     2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Rdpack                  2.4        2022-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 readr                 * 2.1.4      2023-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 remotes                 2.4.2      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 reshape2              * 1.4.4      2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rlang                   1.1.0      2023-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rmarkdown               2.21       2023-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rpart                   4.1.19     2022-10-21 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 Rsolnp                  1.16       2015-12-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rstudioapi            * 0.14       2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 rugarch               * 1.4-9      2022-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 RVAideMemoire         * 0.9-83     2023-06-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 scales                  1.2.1      2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 sessioninfo             1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 shiny                   1.7.4      2022-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 SkewHyperbolic          0.4-0      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 spatial                 7.3-16     2023-01-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 spd                     2.0-1      2015-07-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 StockDistFit          * 1.0.0      2023-05-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 stringi                 1.7.12     2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 stringr               * 1.5.0      2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 survival                3.5-3      2023-02-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 systemfonts             1.0.4      2022-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 textshaping             0.3.6      2021-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tibble                  3.2.1      2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tidyr                 * 1.3.0      2023-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tidyselect              1.2.0      2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 timeDate                4022.108   2023-01-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 timeSeries              4021.105   2022-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 truncnorm               1.0-9      2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tseries               * 0.10-54    2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tsmethods             * 0.3.2      2023-05-19 [1] Github (tsmodels/tsmethods@3f88b94)
 tstests               * 0.1.0      2023-05-19 [1] Github (tsmodels/tstests@8085ab5)
 TTR                     0.24.3     2021-12-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 tzdb                    0.4.0      2023-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 urlchecker              1.0.1      2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 usethis               * 2.1.6      2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 utf8                    1.2.3      2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 uuid                    1.1-0      2022-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 vctrs                   0.6.2      2023-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 withr                   2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xfun                    0.39       2023-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xml2                    1.3.4      2023-04-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xtable                  1.8-4      2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 xts                   * 0.13.1     2023-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 zip                     2.3.0      2023-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)
 zoo                   * 1.8-12     2023-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.3)

 [1] C:/Users/aylaa/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2
 [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/library
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including session info. Your R code is balanced precariously upon a teetering stack of other software and hardware. Maybe the transfer of the data to each worker is slower than the max processor speed. Maybe you only have enough RAM to warrant this level of work by each thread. Perhaps your CPU is [throttling](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000039154/processors/intel-core-processors.html) due to overheating. Impossible to say.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, just a recommendation: Use parallelly::availableCores(omit = 1) instead of detectCores().

Comment: also not a solution, but you can use gnu parallel for windows, which communicates with the cores much more fluently than any R package could.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once due to the usage of Fortran code implemented in a specific function (multiroot from package rootSolve). Changing the default setting to useFortran = F helped me out. Maybe your problem is related to something similar.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35292708)